# isset($_POST['name']) issue after server change

Tags: php

`isset($_POST['name'])` returns `false` if I don't enter a value for `name`.

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Earlier the `isset($_POST['name'])` always return `true` even if we didn't enter a value in the form filed. But after changing the server, `isset($_POST['name'])` returns `true` only if there is a value for `name`.

This is an ajax post. In fact $_POST['name'] itself is not there when var_dump($_POST). But it's there in firebug and LiveHTTP Headers.

Comment: Properly because that the new/other server uses a different php version than the old server.

Comment: php version change perhaps. anyway are you sure that  parameters are correctly submitted? check your browser network.

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST)` to see if the field is really posted. `isset`should return true foir any variable that is not `null`

Comment: This is an ajax post. In fact $_POST['name'] itself is not there when var_dump($_POST). But it's there in firebug and LiveHTTP Headers.

Comment: Your last comment is a bit unclear - can you share screenshot of your firebug console and of the var_dump output?

Comment: You haven't got more than one name="name" input statement in the submitting program have you?  Or possibly unclosed quotes which means that the name="name" isn't being passed correctly for PHP

Answer (score 1):

Isset --> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

eg:

```
$foo = 1;
if (isset($foo)) {
    echo "Foo is set\n";
} else {
    echo "Foo is not set\n";
}
if (isset($bar)) {
    echo "Bar is set\n";
} else {
    echo "Bar is not set\n";
}
```

output "Foo is set" and "Bar is not set"

isset($_POST['name']) returns "true" only if there is a value for "name"--> Its working fine

Comment: But there **is** a value for `$_POST['name']` which is `""`. Empty string **isn't** `null`.